# Docker in docker fails after 32 iterations

Tags: docker, recursion, dockerfile

Docker provides [docker:dind](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker), a docker-in-docker image that works out the headaches for running a docker instance *within* another docker instance. Per the instructions, the command to start an internal instance looks like

```
docker run --memory=30g --rm --privileged -d --network dind-network --network-alias docker -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs -v dind-certs-ca:/certs/ca -v dind-certs-client:/certs/client dindx1
```

Out of curiosity, I wanted to see how far I could recursively create docker-in-docker. To prevent the re-downloading of the image within each nested instance, I built a template image and carry it through each iteration (MRE below):

```makefile
docker build -t dindx0 .
docker run $(RUN_ARGS) --name dindx0 dindx0
docker commit dindx0 dindx1 
docker save dindx1 | gzip > dindx1.tar.gz
docker kill dindx0
docker cp dindx1.tar.gz dindx1:/project
docker exec dindx1 docker load -i dindx1.tar.gz
```

This works up to exactly 32 instances and fails with the curious error:

```sh
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380:
starting container process caused: process_linux.go:402: getting the final child's pid
from pipe caused: EOF: unknown.
```

Any thoughts on how I can push past this limitation?

Comment: Small question, just to rule out a misunderstanding around what docker can do: _why_ do you (think you) need docker inside docker, when separate docker images can run and talk to each other via the `host.docker.internal` and `gateway.docker.internal` network names already? What can plain docker images not do that requires docker-in-docker at all?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans a fair question, and I think for (one deep) docker-in-docker, the link in my question goes through some use cases. To go deeper I don't _need_ it for anything, it's more of an intellectual curiosity but one that exposes some interesting edge cases. Why does it get stuck at 32? I'm sure there is some configuration setting that is holding it back and learning about that has it's own value.

Comment: Is your system 64 bit or 32? 32 sounds very bitmask-y and much power of two-y

Comment: This sounds like a question to _actually_ ask the Docker folks over on https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues... will it be useful to even a single person? Absolutely not, but it's almost certainly an implementation limit that should be in the docs somewhere =)

Comment: @Sylwester 64 bit. I agree 32 is a very curious number to fail at.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans per your suggestion, an issue has been filed here: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/14354 I'll update this question with my own answer if I get a resolution there.